# Localstack terraform lambda function SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name

Tags: ssl, https, terraform, localstack

I used `Localstack + terraform` to deploy a lambda function locally (using docker-compose). In my lambda function, i wrote my logic using javascript and call HTTPs to outside using `axios` library.

```
const external_https_url = 'https://appid.appsync-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/graphql';
const resp = await axios.post(
    `${external_https_url}`,
    {
      query,
      variables: queryVariables
    },
    {
      headers: {
        'x-api-key': apiKey
      }
    }
  );
```

The error I got

```
2023-10-14 13:56:39 werkzeug.exceptions.NotFound: 404 Not Found: The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.
2023-10-14 13:56:39 
2023-10-14 13:56:39 The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
```

And then

```
'localstack.aws.protocol.parser.OperationNotFoundParserError: Unable to find operation for request to service appsync: POST
```

Futher, i open my Lambda container and go to its terminal. I used `curl`

```
curl --location 'https://appid.appsync-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/graphql' \
--header 'x-api-key: apikey' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
  "query":"query MyQuery($email: String!) {\n  testCallHttp(\n    email: $email)\n}",
  "variables": {
    "email":"myemail""
  },
  "operationName":"MyQuery"
}
'
```

I got error

```
curl: (60) SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name 'appid.appsync-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com'
More details here: https://curl.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.
```

Can you help me on this one? How to configure my Lambda docker container that runs on localstack to pass SSL/TLS HTTPs calling to external website. Many thanks.

I can see that, If i stand at the root `localstack_main` docker container, the curl is working well. No issues complaint on SSL/TLS HTTPs certificate.

My docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  localstack:
    container_name: '${LOCALSTACK_DOCKER_NAME-localstack_main}'
    image: localstack/localstack-pro:latest
    networks:
      - myproject_be_tf
    ports:
      - '127.0.0.1:4566:4566'
      - '127.0.0.1:4510-4559:4510-4559'
      - '127.0.0.1:443:443'
      - '127.0.0.1:53:53'
      - '127.0.0.1:53:53/udp'
    environment:
      - DEBUG=1
      - SERVICES=lambda,dynamodb,sns,sqs
      - PERSISTENCE=${PERSISTENCE-}
      - LOCALSTACK_API_KEY=${LOCALSTACK_API_KEY-}
      - DOCKER_HOST=unix:///var/run/docker.sock
      - LAMBDA_RUNTIME_ENVIRONMENT_TIMEOUT=30
      - LAMBDA_DOCKER_FLAGS="-e NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS=/var/lib/localstack/cache/server.test.pem.crt"
      - LAMBDA_EXECUTOR=docker
      - LAMBDA_REMOTE_DOCKER=true
      - LAMBDA_DOCKER_NETWORK=myproject_be_tf
    volumes:
      - '${LOCALSTACK_VOLUME_DIR:-./volume}:/var/lib/localstack'
      - '/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock'
    logging:
      driver: 'json-file'
      options:
        max-size: '50m'
networks:
  myproject_be_tf:
    attachable: true
    name: myproject_be_tf
```

Many thanks for your kind help.

I tried many way to mount the volume of my Lambda function docker container to the cert.crt file but not successfully.